# How to dowload csv file containing HTML tags

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel, csv

I'm trying to download data from mysql database. One field in DB contains HTML tags.

When I try to open downloaded csv this file in excel it works wrong, because of tabulation and HTML tags. Is there any way to open it correctly in excel?

My php script:

```
<?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "root"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "ud-for-downloading-items";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "oc_product_description"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "oc_product_description";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "csv";
//header info for browser
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM

/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   
?>
```

UPDATE: added images

[image: data in csv]
[image: how excel parse it]

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Please explain "it works wrong". Also, adding a screenshot of the output will help us help you better.

Comment: You might like to look at a library called [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User-documentation)

Comment: You should stop using `@` to suppress errors. Handle errors correctly instead.

Comment: You might consider using PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function, rather than a bad homebrew

Comment: But if you have html markup stored in your database, then you'll get that html markup in your csv, unless you remove it

Comment: Moreover, it seems that the html content had been properly encoded before it was saved into the database. If you want the html code back, then you need to decode data.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, I solved it using PHPexcel. I knew about it, but now tried and it work great.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at those 2 functions:
`htmlentities()` encodes al html into chars (e.g. `&quot`)
`html_entity_decode()` goes backwords, converting all the matching chars to html elements.

You could them during you data transfer, based on your needs.
If this won't work you could try a final shot at `filter_var()`